# How can i get table row with codes in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get "`<div class="value"><tr><td>blabl</td><td>blabla2</td></tr></div>`" with jquery and i try like this

```
a=$response.filter('div.value').html();
```

it returns only like this `blablblabla2` but i want to full code like `<tr><td>blabl</td><td>blabla2</td></tr>`. How can i do ?

thanks.

Comment: your html is invalid, `div`'s cannot wrap `table` elements like `tr` and `td`

Answer (score 1):

A `tr` tag must be inside of a `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot` or `table` tags. If you use a `table` tag instead of `div`, you get html values with:

```
a=$response.filter('table.value').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the property innerHtml.. this can be used for any DOM element...